# HTTP Interceptor caching Firebase IdToken of previous user

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the IdToken and automatically apply it to the header via HttpInterceptor, but for some reason it gets the previously signed in user's token. If the app is deleted and reinstalled, it does not work the first time you register a user, and only works upon second registration but again it uses the previous user's token. Here's my code:

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    IdToken: string;
    authState: any;

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => 
        {
            this.authState = user;

            user.getIdToken(true).then((idToken => 
            {
                this.IdToken = idToken;
            }));
        });
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': this.IdToken
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

From what I know, getIdToken(true) is supposed to refresh it but looks like it's not working here.